# vim: changing background of rows past "scrolloff"

Tags: editor, vim

I use:

```
set scrolloff=10
```

in my ~/.vimrc so that search results don't annoyingly appear at the end of the vim screen.

This also means that I cannot edit the top 10 and bottom 10 lines of the screen. Is there a way to (mildly) darken these rows so I 'feel' that they are off editing limits until I scroll further?

The real kicker is that scrolloff is not in effect at the beginning and end of a file (because then one cannot ever edit those lines), and ideally the greying out should know this as well.

Comment: No way I could think of, but you could maybe remap `n` and `N` to `nzz` and `Nzz` if you want search results to be at the middle…

Comment: @Benoit: I didn't know there was such a thing as n|Nzz! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such option in Vim.